# Best Time for Back Door Roth IRA Contributions

Tags: ira, roth-ira

I want to contribute to Roth IRA but due to income limits I cannot. I am already have a Traditional IRA account with funds in it. I can move certain amount to ROTH IRA as a backdoor contribution. My question is for 2022, what will be a good time to move $12000 to Roth IRA (even though conversion does not have limits - $6000 per spouse and in different Roth IRA accounts).

My plan is to contribute certain amount to Traditional next year and then at certain date move the funds to Roth IRA through the conversion.

My question is when in 2022 should I plan to rollover small funds $6000 per spouse from Traditional to Roth.

Comment: Is the money in your traditional IRA from non-deductible contributions? Or is it pre-tax money like from deductible contributions or a 401(k) rollover? It's not clear to me if you're asking about making new contributions and converting them, or converting money already in the account.

Comment: Currently money is in 401K pre tax Traditional IRA account. I also have retirement ROTH IRA account. Due to my income next year, I will be contributing to the traditional IRA and converting $12K per year from traditional to ROTH. My question is what is the best time to perform the conversion each year.

Comment: If you have a significant amount from a pre-tax 401(k) rollover in a traditional IRA, then the backdoor Roth will be partially taxable. See https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Backdoor_Roth#Cautions. Otherwise, there really is no "best time" to perform the conversion.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I don't plan to convert all of my 401 pre tax to ROTH since I don't have the money right now to pay for the tax. But I plan to convert $12K yearly from traditional to Roth. Ok. So there is no best time, this means I can convert at the end of year.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me what you're doing. Are you converting pre-tax 401(k) money to Roth? Or traditional IRA money from a pre-tax 401(k) rollover to a Roth? Is this in addition to a backdoor Roth (i.e. non-deductible traditional IRA contributions followed by Roth conversion)?

Comment: Traditional IRA from pre-tax 401K rollover to ROTH IRA

Comment: I think there is a confusion about terminology here. When people say "backdoor Roth IRA contribution", they mean a contribution to Traditional IRA followed by a conversion to Roth IRA. The point is that, when done correctly, it accomplishes the same thing as a regular Roth IRA contribution (i.e. moves money from a taxable account into Roth IRA, without paying any tax in the process), except without income limits. It seems the OP is simply referring to a conversion of existing Traditional IRA funds into Roth IRA. This is not what is usually called a "backdoor Roth IRA contribution".

Comment: @user102008 Right, but OP also mentions a couple things that makes it sound like he does mean backdoor Roth, e.g. income limits and contributing to traditional IRA and then converting. So I can't make sense of what's going on.

Comment: OK. Let me try again. I have a Traditional IRA (401 Rollover). I also have a Roth IRA. My income will exceed the limits of Roth IRA contributions. Now I still want to contribute to Roth IRA. My plan is to take some amount ($6000) from my Tradtional IRA and convert to Roth. This is called backdoor Roth IRA contributions since due to my income I cannot contribute directly. My question is what (if any) is the best time do transfer $ from trad to Roth.

Comment: In that case, as @user102008 said, this is _not_ a backdoor Roth IRA contribution, it is just a standard, taxable Roth conversion.

Comment: Currently, all the funds in a Traditional IRA is through the 401 pre tax rollover. So if I move $12K into Roth IRA I will have to pay tax on 12K right?

Comment: Correct. If you later make non-deductible contributions to your traditional IRA and then convert, the conversion will be partially taxable based on the ratio of the deductible/pre-tax balance of the traditional IRA over the total balance. For example if your traditional IRA has $6k, then you do a non-deductible contribution of $6k, then convert $6k, only $3k will be taxable. This calculation is done separately for each spouse (IRAs are individual accounts).

Comment: I guess the biggest question is that when I retire will my income be more or less. If it will be less then I can just leave it in a Traditional IRA and not contribute to Roth. Unfortunately, at this time I am not sure if it will be less or more but if I have to guess then my income will be less in the future.

Comment: For most people their income in retirement is lower, often significantly so. Therefore I think Roth conversions probably don't make sense for you right now. But if you currently have access to a 401(k), you could roll your traditional IRA into it, and then do the backdoor Roth.

Comment: Thanks @CraigW I am currently 42 so do you think I should take $$ from Traditional IRA and covert them to ROTH IRA so I don't have to pay tax on the gains when I retire in 20 years. The main problem is that I have $600K in Traditional IRA which means I don't have money to pay the tax on all 600K.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing your full circumstances, but as I said in my answer, I personally would not do conversions now. Don't get trapping into thinking you'll end up ahead by paying the tax now before your investments grow further. The main consideration is tax rate now versus tax rate in retirement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot process a tax-free "backdoor" Roth IRA contribution if you have existing pre-tax funds or earnings in **any** traditional IRA account.

If the amount of the pre-tax funds + earnings is low or you're in a low tax bracket, it may make sense to effectively convert the pre-tax funds to Roth at your marginal tax rate, but so long as untaxed earnings exist, you cannot perform a true backdoor Roth.

Note that some employer 401k plans may allow you to roll in pre-tax IRA funds. This is subject to plan rules and may provide a means for you to process tax-free backdoor Roth IRA contributions.

If you meet the requirements for a backdoor Roth contribution or are willing to pay tax on the existing funds + earnings, the timing generally does not matter, aside from any interactions with your other income in the same tax year.

Comment: Thanks! My plan now is to contribute to the Traditional IRA and also each year move some amount from Traditional IRA to Roth IRA. This way I am still contributing to some account and slowly moving some funds to Roth IRA.

Comment: What you're doing sounds similar to a "Roth ladder" if you want to do more independent reserach, although you're still working/contributing at the same time (ok!)

Comment: Note as well that you can make nondeductible contributions to IRA and convert at a later date (when you're in a lower income bracket).  You'll owe taxes on the earnings but it may be less taxes than your current marginal rate for the pro rata earnings at this time.  Definitely keep track of your Form 8606s though

Answer (score 1):

The answer may well be "never". You are likely in a relatively high tax bracket right now, judging from the fact that your income is high enough that you can't make direct Roth IRA contributions. In the past you probably picked a pre-tax instead of Roth 401(k) for this reason. By doing Roth conversions now, you're essentially reversing this decision. Generally this only makes sense if your tax bracket drops significantly, which it doesn't sound like is the case for you now. But if you're set on doing it, it's generally better to do it as soon as possible. Investments tend to go up in value, so the sooner you convert, pay the taxes, and get them into Roth the better.